# How can i select a many to many relationship table?

Tags: sql, database

I have the following tables that im trying to pull data from.

```
[ tutors  ]    [ majors ]   [ courses ]  [  bundle ]   [bundle_courses]
|id       |    |id      |   |id       |  |id       |   |id            |
|name     |    |title   |   |title    |  |tutor_id |   |course_id     |
|email    |                 |major_id |  |major_id |   |bundle_id     |
|major_id |
```

So each tutor has many bundles that contain many courses that the tutor teaches. Each bundle contains courses from the same major hence the major id. So I need to select the tutor's name each bundle they have and the courses associated with that bundle and what the major is for the bundle. I'm not sure how to go about it and I was wondering if it's possible to do on a single query. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You are looking for `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

First, find out how to join 1 table, then join many tables in a single select statement

I'm not going to do *all* your homework for you but it should look something like

```
SELECT <fields>
  FROM <some_table>
  JOIN <another_table> ...
  JOIN  ....
    :
    :
  WHERE ...
```

Comment: Yes thats what i was using sorry i probably should have put down what query I tried before. I was doing the multiple Inner Joins. I just got confused with the placement of the variable. I finally got it to work and this is how the query looks like. This is working for me. select T.name, C.title, M.title FROM tutors T INNER JOIN bundles B on B.tutor_id=T.id INNER JOIN majors M on B.major_id=M.id INNER JOIN bundle_course BC ON BC.bundle_id=B.id INNER JOIN courses C on BC.course_id=C.id

Comment: Bingo! Good job.